# Как найти определение функции которая импортируется вместе с модулем в python

Tags: python, библиотеки, поиск-библиотек, модули

Хочу поглядеть на реализацию некоторых функций, классов из библиотек `Python`. В частности из numpy класс `numpy.array`.
Обычно я просто делаю import numpy as np. Но я бы хотел понимать где лежит определение этого класса. `np.__file__` даёт лишь путь к файлу, который запускается при импорте пакета numpy. Но внутри этого скрипта огромное количество `from -//- import -//-`. Неужели нет более удобного способа для поиска библиотекив `Python`, чем  самостоятельный рекурсивный поиск по всем модулям?
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: в ИДЕ кликнуть на название с нажатой кнопкой Ctrl. Работает пркатически во всех "взрослых" IDE.

Comment: Как быть, если среда "Cannot find declaration to go to."?

Comment: не знаю. Не сталкивался. Какой пакет и какая ИДЕ?

Comment: numpy в PyCharm...

Comment: Ну не знаю. Я кликаю на ``numpy`` в IDEA (у которой, я так понимаю, одинаковый движок с PyCharm) и попадаю в файл ``__init__.py``. Кликаю на``sum()`` в ``np.sum()`` и попадаю на строку ``def sum(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=np._NoValue, initial=np._NoValue):`` в файле ``fromnumeric.py``

Comment: Оказывается я забыл подключить интерпретатор к проекту... Детская ошибка, но заняла уйму времени. Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 0):

При импорте модуля в блоке для кода в PyCharm нажимаешь Ctrl + ПКМ на функцию про которую хочешь узнать, тебя перекинет на сам код функции и документацию, если хочешь узнать про все функции из numpy то просто импортируй numpy и нажми по нему данными клавишами. И вроде со всеми функциями так работает